# Endpoints in pancake swap API are not working

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, binance-smart-chain

I am trying to fetch data from the pancake swap API [here](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-info-api/blob/develop/v2-documentation.md) but the route they posted to fetch current token pairs is not working [here](https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/pairs)

I haven't yet written a code, I am just trying to get pair of tokens using the link below in their documentation with postman

```
 https://api.pancakeswap.info/api/v2/pairs
```

and i am getting this error

```
 {
   "error":{
    "code":500,
    "message":"first block was not fetched"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question - provide code example of what you've tried, and elaborate on what "is not working" means in your case. Does the API return an error message (what is the error)? Does your code throw an exception (what is the exception)?

Comment: Hey petr, just edited my question but i haven't written any code yet

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a support question for a third party API server and belongs to the support term of the service provider.